Fast standardised DCT algorithms
I'm wondering if the industry has converged on a standard approach to implement fast, efficient DCT ?
Seems like there are many algorithms out there, e.g.:
1 A Fast Computational Algorithm for the Discrete Cosine Transform (Chen, Smith, Fralick, 1977)
2 A new algorithm to compute the discrete cosine Transform (Lee, 1984)
3 Practical fast 1-D DCT algorithms with 11 multiplications (Loeffler et al, 1989)
For 8-point DCT, 3) seems pretty good (optimal number of multiplications), whereas 2) generalises to higher point DCT more easily (and higher point DCTs seem quite common nowadays).
I was thinking that after so many years the industry would have converged on a single approach?  (I know that for many software purposes, people would just use standard libraries, but I guess that's not an option for assembler/hardware implementations).

Papers you mention are 3-5 decades old. I well remember how slow PC's were at mid '80's. Processors at that time were not that fast nor compilers as optimized as today so, one multiplication less meant much then. Today you have fast multi core processors, SIMD and GPGPU -computing technologies, highly optimized compilers, etc. for to help improve performance of these tasks to level letting you focus on accuracy and other features as for an example.
